# Split name column to csv file

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, csv

How can I easily transform columns information to CSV line or file output?

Input (From file or excel column):

```
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
ABC4
```

Output (To file or excel line):

```
ABC21,ABC2,ABC3,ABC4
```

I don't want to use VBScripting in Excel, I just want a very simple way to do it. Yet, if possible/known, I would not discard a powershell script to do so.

Thanks!

EDIT: Managed to do it in the most stupid way possible, transposed the column range into row range then saved it as CSV.

Comment: If you would accept a powershell script, then why not write one? Your question reads like "please do my work", which isn't the point of this site. We're here to help about specific problems, so if you tried to write your script and got stuck, then we'd be able to help. As it is, this question has many different solutions and is therefore very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way to get it done in Powershell:

$a="";get-content C:\test.txt | foreach-object { $a = $a + "$_," };$a=$a.Trim(",");$a